# Run CURL commands in SSRS Report

Tags: curl, reporting-services

Is it possible to run CURL commands in an SSRS report? Specifically, for an external image source. I know I can directly use something like this:
https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/de6ae2f1-9faa-49a2-b09f-a0e5107ab1e2_1.c99ab1ce24d572916f66d6071dfe8ae4.jpeg?odnWidth=612&odnHeight=612&odnBg=ffffff
to show an image, but I need to use HTTP POST. Any idea?

Thanks